# Finalization of ConcurrentBag containing unmanaged objects

Tags: c#, idisposable, finalizer

I'm having trouble handling Dispose/Finalization correctly with a `ConcurrentBag` that contains unmanaged objects. Running the below code (usually) produces an `ObjectDisposedException` (`Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'The ThreadLocal object has been disposed.'.`) on the call to `TryTake()`.

Presumably in this case the garbage collector is destroying the `ConcurrentBag` before calling A's finalizer. I had thought this would only the case if the `ConcurrentBag` itself implemented a finalizer. Is it the case that one should never touch managed objects during the finalization path?

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<object> _collection = new ConcurrentBag<object>();

    public A(string value)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    ~A() 
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose() => Dispose(true);

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {}

        object value;
        while (_collection.TryTake(out value))
        {
            // Cleanup value
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger the exception:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A(null);
}
```

The following seems to work around this specific issue but I'm unsure if this is *safe*. Is there a perfectly safe implementation for this scenario?

```
while (_collection.IsEmpty == false)
{
    object value;
    _collection.TryTake(out value);
    // Cleanup value
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When code is executing from the finalizer (`disposing` is `false`) the only things you are allowed to do is use static methods with no state, variables local to the function, and fields that inherit from `CriticalFinalizerObject` (unless you are in a finalizer for a `CriticalFinalizerObject` then you can't use them).

Because `ConcurrentBag` does not inherit from `CriticalFinalizerObject` you can not rely on it not being finalized when your own finalizer is run. Both `this` and the `_collection.m_locals` variable [Sign mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38925242/80274) both get put in to the finalization queue at the same time when `this` becomes unreachable. The order the queue is processed is not deterministic.

There is a great article "[IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)" that goes in depth on what is actually happening when somthing gets finalized and provides some better patterns than the traditional `private void Dispose(bool disposing)` pattern Microsoft recommends.

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense. 

Based on Stephen Cleary's article, the correct implementation would be to wrap the unmanaged objects in IDisposable wrappers (what he calls Level 0) that handle the dirty work of considering finalization. This allows the higher level, my class A (i.e. Level 1), class to only concern itself with the Dispose path and ignore the finalization path.

Comment: The only thing you have incorrect is level 0 objects should derive from `SafeHandle` not just `IDisposeable`, but other than that, yea.

Answer (score 2):

The full stack trace of the object disposed exception is

```
   at System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1.GetValueSlow()
   at System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1.get_Value()
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.GetThreadList(Boolean forceCreate)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.TryTakeOrPeek(T& result, Boolean take)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.TryTake(T& result)
   at A.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at A.Finalize()
```

Which means that the disposed object lives inside ConcurrentBag which is odd since ConcurrentBag isn't IDisposable. Digging through the [source of ConcurrentBag](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs,e0526452d6ea4847) shows that it has a `ThreadLocal` which is IDisposable and is used in the `GetThreadList` method. Weirdly enough if you use a plain old `foreach` loop you avoid the `ThreadLocal` and it looks like everything works the way you would expect.

```
foreach (var value in _collection)
{
   // Cleanup value
}
```

Despite this digging I don't have an explanation for how the `ThreadLocal` got disposed.

Comment: It got disposed because `_collection` was considered unreachable when `a` became unreachable, which made `_collection.m_locals` unreachable and put in to the finalizer queue. The `m_locals` finalizer got ran before the finalizer for `A` got a chance to run because `ThreadLocal<T>` does not inherit from `CriticalFinalizerObject`.