# Assuring that Objects are Disposed before Finalization in C#

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

I have trouble implementing a C# wrapper for [rcl](http://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/rcl/) which has a struct named `rcl_context_s` encapsulating non-global state for some `rcl_node_s` structs.
There are functions for finalizing these structs which require that all nodes of a given context are finalized before the context itself is finalized.

I implemented `IDisposable` for the context wrapper which has a private `Dictionary` containing all associated nodes by disposing all nodes before calling the rcl finalization function.

I want the context to dispose itself (and all associated nodes) on finalization if it has not been disposed yet but since the disposing is happening during finalization I cant count on other objects like the `Dictionary` for not being finalized.

I thought that using `GC.SuppressFinalize` and `GC.ReRegisterForFinalize` for preventing the `Dictionary` from being finalized before the wrapper is disposed could solve this issue since the node wrappers have no finalizer because they can rely on the context wrapper to dispose them if the user forgets it.

I want to know if there are any problems with my idea or betters ways of solving this problem since I am not that experienced in C# and its (possible) quirks.

#### Update

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923820/finalization-of-concurrentbag-containing-unmanaged-objects) question which had a similar problem and seems to hint that preventing the `Dictionary` from being finalized does not prevent its internals from being finalized and thus becoming unusable.

Maybe I can solve the problem by allowing the node wrappers to dispose themselves on finalization and using `CriticalFinalizerObject` to make the context wrappers finalizer run after them but that would still be unsafe since the finalizers of the node wrappers are not guaranteed to run.

Comment: Silly question: do you use your "context wrapper" with `using` keyword?

Comment: That should be the normal usage, but I don't want to rely on users doing it.

Comment: Then your IDisposable makes no sence as nobody 'll call it.

Comment: Implementing `IDisposable` tells the consumer, "Look, you better put a `using` on this if you want proper behavior. Otherwise, it's your fault if you run out of resources because I gave you the means to prevent it."

Comment: The `rcl` docs unfortunately use the term "finalize" in a way roughly comparable to what C# uses `Dispose` for (deterministic cleanup), but managed finalization is really something else entirely. Nor should it be confused with garbage collection -- a `Dictionary` has no finalizer, for example, so as posed your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: To make things slightly more confusing, because your managed classes *are* wrapping unmanaged resources, they *could* be given a finalizer that calls what `rcl` calls "finalizers". If you do so, you don't have to worry about private members like a `Dictionary` not being available -- if an object needs finalization, it won't be garbage collected until that's happened, meaning all of its members remain alive by virtue of that. The garbage collector will never call `Dispose`, and user code will never call the finalizer -- these mechanisms are separate, though the code is often shared.

Comment: For a use case like this, where the process can be expected to generate many unmanaged objects that all need to be cleaned up, you can also consider a model where nothing at all is disposed or finalized and instead everything is expected to be cleaned up by the OS when the process terminates. I don't know if that's appropriate for what's being wrapped here (it's not appropriate for a long-running process that is expected to service many different clients, or for hardware registrations that won't be cleaned up by the OS), but it can greatly simplify things as well as improve performance.

Comment: Not handling users forgetting to dispose a context is possible since a context is usually created early on application startup and finalized on application shutdown.